# What is "mupigane" in Swahili?

Tags: verbs, conjugation, bantu

In this sentence: "Wazazi waliwaambia watoto wao: 'Badala ya kufa nyumbani nendeni mupigane.'", I assume "mupigane" is a conjugated form of the verb "kupiga" (fight). However, I never encountered a verbal form starting with mu- and ending with -ne. Or is it a different verb altogether?

**Edit** I suspect the *mu-* prefix has something to do with the locative class, due to the presence of the "kwenda" verb. In this case I would expect the locative *-ni*, not *-ne* (which I've never seen before).

Comment: Google translates the sentence as _The parents told he children: 'Instead of dying at home, go and fight.'_, and identifies the language as Swahili, so it would appear indeed to be a conjugation of _kupiga_. Just guessing from the Google translation, I would guess that it might be a plural imperative.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I interpreted it as grammatically equivalent to "go to fight", i.e. "nendeni" is the imperative (which it is), and "mupigane" is subordinate to it.

Comment: I have no familiarity with any of the Bantu languages, so I'll defer to your presumed expertise. In English, I believe that's still considered the imperative, and I'd have "expanded" on the English "go and fight" into the archaic form "go forth and fight", still with both verbs ("go [forth]" and "fight") in the imperative.

Comment: I don't know what _mu-_ is, but as for the suffixes I can tell you that _mupigane_ is not infinitive, but a subjunctive form of _-pigana_ “beat one another, fight” (reciprocal of _-piga_ “beat”) with the final _-a_ substituted for the subjunctive _-e_.

Comment: Seconding Yellow Sky: this is a subjunctive reciprocal. But I don't know what the mu- could be except the locative class, and that doesn't make sense here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Mupigane* is not imperative, it is a **subjunctive** form of *-pigana* “beat one another = fight” (which is reciprocal of *-piga* “beat”) with the final *-a* substituted for the subjunctive *-e*.

The Wiktionary conjugation [chart](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pigana#Conjugation) for *-pigana* does list *mupigane*, it is among the “Forms with object concords” as 
**Positive subjunctive with 2nd p. pl. subject and c3/c11/c14 object**.

The translation is something like “you should fight it” / “that you fight it”.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I had not figured out that this had something to do with the reciprocal -na. I guess I didn't know the object concords terminations, so that's helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Mu- is either 2pl subject or object prefix, or cl. 1 object prefix. We can rule out an object prefix interpretation based on the syntax of *-pigan-* "beat each other" (too many object arguments). The stem is composed of -*pig-* "beat" plus the reciprocal extension -an-. Final -e is the subjunctive marker, so the form can roughly translate this as "2pl. should beat each other". When you have a "conjoined imperative" like "go and cook", "shut up and listen" etc. the first verb can be imperative but the second is in the subjunctive, so "go fight e.o." would be a good translation of *nendeni mupigane*.